# Python scoping and if-then statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to set a variable based on the value of another variable in python. But when I ask for the value of the variable set in the `if`-`then` statement, it can't find the variable, obviously because it is now out of scope.

Consider the following:

```
>>> a = True
>>> if a:
...     b=1
... else:
...     b=2
>>> print b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Is there a pythonic way to write this? For example, the following code works, but is it "the right way" to write it, or is there a better way?

```
>>> b = None
>>> if a:
...     b=1
... else:
...     b=2
... 
>>> b
1
```

Comment: What do you mean?  Your first example works fine in all versions of Python.

Comment: I agree with iCodez -- 'b' is defined in python2.7 when I try your example.

Comment: It really really really should work as you've written it. Scoping in Python is done on a function level, so b should be in scope.

Comment: Could you show actual interpreter output, copy-pasted from an actual interpreter session? Your examples have visible inconsistencies with the actual way the Python interpreter requires you to provide input.

Comment: It was because I put it in wrong, that's why it didn't work. sorry guys :(

Comment: @djhaskin987 Check my answer for a simpler way of assigning like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple assignment, you could use [python's equivalent of ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/1860929) :

```
>>> a = True
>>> b = 1 if a else 2
>>> b
1
```

---

Also, I can't reproduce your given example,

```
In [1]: a = True

In [2]: if a:
   ...:     b = 1
   ...: else:
   ...:     b = 2
   ...:     

In [3]: print b
1
```

Comment: In my years of Python, I've never seen an concise assignment like this. Is this even in the documentation? Thanks for the eye opener.

Comment: You can use that everywhere: assignments, comprehensions, function arguments... it's quite excellent. :)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: [Here's the relevant documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)